# when i run flutter pub get i get this error "date_picker_timeline" depends on intl ^0.16.0 and "flutter_localizations" depends on intl 0.17.0

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

Because date_picker_timeline >=1.1.0 depends on intl ^0.16.0 and every version of flutter_localizations from sdk depends on intl 0.17.0, date_picker_timeline >=1.1.0 is incompatible with flutter_localizations from sdk.
And because easy_localization >=2.1.0+1 depends on flutter_localizations any from sdk, date_picker_timeline >=1.1.0 is incompatible with easy_localization >=2.1.0+1.
So, because TimyTimeMain depends on both date_picker_timeline ^1.1.3 and easy_localization ^2.3.3, version solving failed.

```
intl: ">=0.16.0 <=0.17.0-nullsafety.2"
easy_localization: ^2.3.3
date_picker_timeline: ^1.1.3
```

Comment: can you post the output of `flutter doctor`?

Comment: The `date_picker_timeline`package has a new version. Try to upgrade it: ^1.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Date Picker has a new version -

```
dependencies:
  date_picker_timeline: ^1.2.1
```

https://pub.dev/packages/date_picker_timeline/install

Please update this data in your pubspec.yaml

Also, you can check the version for the Intl package and others if necessary
https://pub.dev/packages/intl/install

Comment: In The package date_picker_timeline is solved but with easy_localization the problem not solved

Comment: What version do you have for Intl package?
It looks like they have v.16 as a stable but you need v.17 (this version in review) https://pub.dev/packages/intl/versions.  But you can try to use it anyway   intl: ^0.17.0

Comment: I try intl: ">=0.16.0 <=0.17.0-nullsafety.2''. And I try easy_localization: ^2.3.3

Comment: remove -nullsafety.2 and leave just 0.17.0

Comment: because TimyTimeMain depends on both date_picker_timeline ^1.2.1 and easy_localization ^2.3.3, version solving failed.

Comment: intl: ">=0.16.0 <=0.17.0"  easy_localization: ^2.3.3  date_picker_timeline: ^1.2.1